# AVFoundation overlay video in real time

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, avfoundation, gpuimage

I capture video via `AVCaptureSession` in `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange` video format. I can't use another format, I need frames on output for recognition. And I use `AVAssetWriter` for write frames to file when frames come in. Now I need add watermark to video in most efficient way as it possible. I look to [`GPUImage`](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) library. I write test project with little changes in library and get great performance. 1280x720 video recorded in real time with overlay `UIView` without lags. After I include `GPUImage` in real project without video overlay, I start get lags in video recording.

How works before (manually):
`Camera -> CMSampleBuffer -> Write to file`

`GPUImage` after dig inside:
`Camera -> CMSampleBuffer -> Shader conversion to RGB -> not sure what also process going here -> Write to file`

So problem is when I use `GPUImage` with simple `Camera->MovieWriter` structure I get lags. When I do writing myself, I do not see any lags. I think problem with conversion to RGB and other stuff that `GPUImage` do.

So my question is:
Can I add watermark (in OpenGL maybe) on frame without RGB conversion? Or what part in `GPUImage` takes more time? Can I overlay `luminanceTexture` and `chrominanceTexture` in shader?